# Nginx returning 444 for PUT and DELETE

Tags: nginx, http

I'm trying to build a REST API through Nginx and everything works fine except when I the requests are PUT or DELETE. In these cases, Nginx returns 444 (no response). I did some research and all I could find was something about Nginx being configured with the "--with-http_dav_module" option. I've checked that with nginx -V and and it seems that it was configured with this.

So, any idea what else could it be?

Comment: Please, show your `nginx -V` and full configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer myself so this one as it might be useful for other absent-minded guys out there.

It seems that nginx config was including a "security" file which specifically denied (444) any request other than GET, POST or HEAD. I've removed that and everything is fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Nginx never returns 444 (no response) for any request unless you configured it to do so. Also it can be a result of using 3rd party modules or patches.